# Using a DFS to compute distance from source node

Tags: c, graph-theory, adjacency-list

I am trying to use a DFS algorithm to calculate the distance from a source node for each node. Currently it outputs a distance of 0 for the source vertex but 1 for all the other vertices, even though there should be a couple with a distance of 2. The printf in the DFS does print out the right order, with the source first then the vertices with distance 1 and then distance 2. So where in the algorithm would I need to put the distance increase.

```
void dfs(int vertex1) {
    graph[vertex1-1].visited = 1;
    printf("%d \n",vertex1);
    struct edge *e;
    e = graph[vertex1-1].edgePtr;

    while (e) {
        if (!(graph[e->vertexIndex - 1].visited)){
            graph[e->vertexIndex - 1].distance++;  
            dfs(e->vertexIndex);
        }     
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Style note: `vertex1` should be an array index, i.e. a number between `0` and `N-1` where N is the number of vertices. If you want the user to see vertex numbers between 1 and N inclusive, then do the adjustment in the `printf`, i.e. `printf("%d\n",vertex1+1);`

Comment: On topic: using a DFS is problematic, since you could travel through multiple vertices, and arrive at a vertex that's next to the starting point. So the DFS doesn't actually give you the information you're trying to find. You should be doing a BFS, since the BFS will visit all of the vertices next to the starting vertex, before venturing farther away.

Comment: Yeah I am going to remove the printf in this function when I make sure that it works, but in a lower function when I print out the actual distances I do make have it like that so vertex 1 shows 1 and not 0 etc.

Comment: True...I am not sure how to implement it though using this struct structure

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a way to make the DFS calculate the distance and it is correct except the last vertex found it says that the distance is 3 instead of 2.

```
5
(2,3)
(1,4)
(1,3)
(3,4)
(4,5)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../HW3/input_error.h"
#define VertexToSearch 1

typedef struct edge {
    int vertexIndex;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
} edge;

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertexKey;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
    int visited;
    int distance;
} vertex;

int vertexCount = 0;
struct vertex graph[];
void load_file(char*);
void insertEdge(int, int, struct vertex[]);
void InsertVertex(int, struct vertex[]);
void printGraph();
void dfs();
void print_distances();
enum error program_error;
int count;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    load_file(argv[1]);
    printGraph();
    dfs(VertexToSearch);
    print_distances();
    return 0;
}

void load_file(char* filename) {

    int vertex1;
    int vertex2;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("%s did not open\n", filename);
        program_error = FILE_FAILED_TO_OPEN;
        exit(program_error);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d", &count);
    graph[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        InsertVertex(i+1, graph);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "\n(%d,%d)", &vertex1, &vertex2);
        insertEdge(vertex1, vertex2, graph);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void InsertVertex(int vertexKey, struct vertex graph[]) {
    graph[vertexCount].vertexKey = vertexKey;
    graph[vertexCount].edgePtr = NULL;
    graph[vertexCount].visited = 0;
    graph[vertexCount].distance = 0;
    vertexCount++;
}

void insertEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, struct vertex graph[]) {
    struct edge *e, *e1, *e2;
    e = graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e1 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e1));
    e1->vertexIndex = vertex2;
    e1->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e1;
    else
        graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr = e1;

    e = graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e2 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e2));
    e2->vertexIndex = vertex1;
    e2->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e2;
    else
        graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr = e2;
}

void printGraph() {
    int i;
    struct edge *e;
    for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        printf("%d(%d)", i+1, graph[i].vertexKey);
        e = graph[i].edgePtr;
        while (e) {
            printf("->%d", e->vertexIndex);
            e = e->edgePtr;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void dfs(int vertex1) {
    graph[vertex1 - 1].visited = 1;

    printf("%d \n", vertex1);
    struct edge *e;
    e = graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (graph[i].visited == 0 && e->vertexIndex != VertexToSearch) {
            graph[i].distance++;
        }
    }
    while (e) {
        if (!(graph[e->vertexIndex - 1].visited)) {
            dfs(e->vertexIndex);
        }
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
}
void print_distances(){
    for(int i = 0;i < count; i++){
           printf("%d %d\n", i+ 1,graph[i].distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for someone to explain why the last vertex is off. I still maintain that a DFS can't work for this.

Comment: How would I implement a BFS then to perform this then??

Comment: I have also edited this to include the entire program

Comment: @user3386109: I created a new thread about an attempt at a BFS like you suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907198/using-bfs-to-compute-distance-between-a-source-and-a-vertex