# Using BFS to compute distance between a source and a vertex

Tags: c, queue, breadth-first-search

I am trying to use adjacency list to compute the distance from a source vertex to the other vertices. I am using a queue to accomplish this however I get the distance of each vertex besides the source as -1, but I am not sure why this is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input_error.h"
#define VertexToSearch 1

typedef struct edge {
    int vertexIndex;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
} edge;

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertexKey;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
    int visited;
    int distance;
} vertex;

typedef struct queue {
    struct vertex v;
    struct queue* next;
}queue;

int vertexCount = 0;
struct vertex graph[];
void load_file(char*);
void insertEdge(int, int, struct vertex[]);
void InsertVertex(int, struct vertex[]);
void printGraph();
void bfs();
void print_distances();
queue* enqueue(queue*,vertex );
vertex dequeue(queue*);

enum error program_error;
int count;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    load_file(argv[1]);
    printGraph();
    bfs();
    print_distances();
    return 0;
}

void load_file(char* filename) {

    int vertex1;
    int vertex2;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("%s did not open\n", filename);
        program_error = FILE_FAILED_TO_OPEN;
        exit(program_error);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d", &count);
    graph[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        InsertVertex(i + 1, graph);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "\n(%d,%d)", &vertex1, &vertex2);
        insertEdge(vertex1, vertex2, graph);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void InsertVertex(int vertexKey, struct vertex graph[]) {
    graph[vertexCount].vertexKey = vertexKey;
    graph[vertexCount].edgePtr = NULL;
    graph[vertexCount].visited = 0;
    graph[vertexCount].distance = -1;
    vertexCount++;
}

void insertEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, struct vertex graph[]) {
    struct edge *e, *e1, *e2;
    e = graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e1 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e1));
    e1->vertexIndex = vertex2;
    e1->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e1;
    else
        graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr = e1;

    e = graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e2 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e2));
    e2->vertexIndex = vertex1;
    e2->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e2;
    else
        graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr = e2;
}

void printGraph() {
    int i;
    struct edge *e;
    for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        printf("%d(%d)", i + 1, graph[i].vertexKey);
        e = graph[i].edgePtr;
        while (e) {
            printf("->%d", e->vertexIndex);
            e = e->edgePtr;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void bfs() {
    graph[0].distance = 0;
    queue* q = NULL;
   q = enqueue(q,graph[0]);
    while(q->next != NULL){
        vertex u = dequeue(q);
        while(u.edgePtr != NULL){
           if(graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex -1 ].distance == -1){
              graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex -1 ].distance = u.distance + 1;
              enqueue(q, graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex -1 ]);
           } 
           u.edgePtr = u.edgePtr->edgePtr;
        }
    }

}

void print_distances() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i + 1, graph[i].distance);
    }
}

queue* enqueue(queue* q,vertex v) {
    queue* new = malloc(sizeof (queue));
    new->next = NULL; 
    new->v = v;
    if (q == NULL) {
        q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
        q = new;
    } else {
        while (q->next != NULL) {
            q = q->next;
        }
        //add new node at the end
        q->next = new;

    }
    return q;
}

vertex dequeue(queue* q) {
    vertex v;
    queue* tempPtr;
    tempPtr = q; //makes temp the address of the node to be deleted
    v = tempPtr->v;
    q = q->next; //sets the new head as the address of the next node

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out, basically my queue implementation was horrible and dequeue was not clearing out the queue, also this `while(q->next != NULL)` was incorrect it should be `while(q != NULL)` Below is the correct implementation of this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input_error.h"
#define VertexToSearch 1

typedef struct edge {
    int vertexIndex;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
} edge;

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertexKey;
    struct edge *edgePtr;
    int visited;
    int distance;
} vertex;

typedef struct queue {
    struct vertex v;
    struct queue* next;
}queue;

int vertexCount = 0;
struct vertex graph[];
queue* q = NULL;
void load_file(char*);
void insertEdge(int, int, struct vertex[]);
void InsertVertex(int, struct vertex[]);
void printGraph();
void bfs();
void print_distances();
void enqueue(vertex);
vertex dequeue();

enum error program_error;
int count;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    load_file(argv[1]);
    printGraph();
    bfs();
    print_distances();
    return 0;
}

void load_file(char* filename) {

    int vertex1;
    int vertex2;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("%s did not open\n", filename);
        program_error = FILE_FAILED_TO_OPEN;
        exit(program_error);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d", &count);
    graph[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        InsertVertex(i + 1, graph);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "\n(%d,%d)", &vertex1, &vertex2);
        insertEdge(vertex1, vertex2, graph);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void InsertVertex(int vertexKey, struct vertex graph[]) {
    graph[vertexCount].vertexKey = vertexKey;
    graph[vertexCount].edgePtr = NULL;
    graph[vertexCount].visited = 0;
    graph[vertexCount].distance = -1;
    vertexCount++;
}

void insertEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, struct vertex graph[]) {
    struct edge *e, *e1, *e2;
    e = graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e1 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e1));
    e1->vertexIndex = vertex2;
    e1->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e1;
    else
        graph[vertex1 - 1].edgePtr = e1;

    e = graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr;
    while (e && e->edgePtr) {
        e = e->edgePtr;
    }
    e2 = (struct edge *) malloc(sizeof (*e2));
    e2->vertexIndex = vertex1;
    e2->edgePtr = NULL;
    if (e)
        e->edgePtr = e2;
    else
        graph[vertex2 - 1].edgePtr = e2;
}

void printGraph() {
    int i;
    struct edge *e;
    for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        printf("%d(%d)", i + 1, graph[i].vertexKey);
        e = graph[i].edgePtr;
        while (e) {
            printf("->%d", e->vertexIndex);
            e = e->edgePtr;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void bfs() {
    graph[0].distance = 0;
   enqueue(graph[0]);
    while(q != NULL){
        vertex u = dequeue();
        while(u.edgePtr != NULL){
       if(graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex - 1].distance == -1){
          graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex - 1].distance = u.distance + 1;
          enqueue(graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex - 1]);
       } 
           u.edgePtr = u.edgePtr->edgePtr;
        }
    }

}

void print_distances() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i + 1, graph[i].distance);
    }
}

void enqueue(vertex v) {
    queue* new = malloc(sizeof (queue));
    new->next = NULL; 
    new->v = v;
    if (q == NULL) {
        q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
        q = new;
    } else {
        while (q->next != NULL) {
            q = q->next;
        }
        //add new node at the end
        q->next = new;

    }
}

vertex dequeue() {
    vertex v;
    queue* tempPtr;
    tempPtr = q; //makes temp the address of the node to be deleted
    v = tempPtr->v;
    q = q->next; //sets the new head as the address of the next node
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Well done! Debugging is a useful skill and it's always the small errors that will keep you busy for a couple hours. I was beginning to wonder if your queue might've been the problem because it was the only thing I hadn't gone over critically because I assumed it was correct.

Comment: @Aaron3468: Yeah I didn't think about that at first, I used a queue that I had used for a different program and changed variable names but forgot to add a couple things to make it work with this project

Answer (score 2):

In `insertVertex(...)`, you call `graph[vertexCount].distance = -1;`.

It is very likely that your code isn't changing distance properly. From what I can see, you set `u.edgePtr->vertexIndex` to the index of the second vertex connected **- 1** (in `insertEdge(...)`). This means you're probably converting from human-readable indexes (1, 2, ... n) into machine-readable indexes (0, 1, ... n-1)

In `bfs()` you shouldn't need to do this a second time! I couldn't find any reason to set `graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex - 1].distance`, but I could be mistaken. I've redone your while loop. Try putting this in `bfs()`:

```
while(u.edgePtr != NULL){
       if(graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex].distance == -1){
          graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex].distance = u.distance + 1;
          enqueue(q, graph[u.edgePtr->vertexIndex]);
       }
```

I'm not sure why *none* of your distances are changing, because your code should still be affecting the distances at `index-1` just fine. Try the fix above and let me know if that was enough to catch the bug or if there might be another one.

Comment: Still getting all -1

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea. Here are some ways to simplify the code

- Use an array based queue with fixed size. The size 256 is ideal since
  the unsigned integer indexes will roll over automatically. Trade-off:
  simple code but no more than 255 items in the queue at any given
  time.
- Use an array of edges. Trade-off: easy to implement the edge array,
  but takes an *O(E)* search to find the edges that originate from any
  given vertex.
- Use the distance to keep track of whether a node has been visited. A
  negative distance means that the vertex has not been visited.
  Trade-off: seems like a win-win to me, simpler code, less space, no
  extra time.
- Use the vertex ID to locate a vertex in the vertex array. Trade-off:
  prevents a malformed edge from crashing your program, but requires an
  *O(V)* search to find the vertex.

Here's the simplified code. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to optimize the code for speed and/or remove the queue limit, as desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Vertex
{
    int id;
    int distance;
};

struct Queue
{
    uint8_t head;
    uint8_t tail;
    void *data[256];
};

int main( void )
{
    int edge[][2] = { {2,3}, {1,4}, {1,3}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {0,0} };
    struct Vertex vertex[] = { {1,0}, {2,-1}, {3,-1}, {4,-1}, {5,-1}, {0,0} };
    struct Queue q = { 0, 0 };

    q.data[q.head++] = &vertex[0];
    while ( q.tail != q.head )
    {
        struct Vertex *src = q.data[q.tail++];
        for ( int i = 0; edge[i][0] > 0; i++ )
            for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
                if ( edge[i][j] == src->id )
                {
                    int destID = edge[i][(j+1)%2];
                    struct Vertex *dest;
                    for ( dest = vertex; dest->id > 0; dest++ )
                        if ( dest->id == destID )
                            break;

                    if ( dest->distance < 0 )
                    {
                        dest->distance = src->distance + 1;
                        q.data[q.head++] = dest;
                    }
                }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; vertex[i].id > 0; i++ )
        printf( "Vertex %d is at distance %d\n", vertex[i].id, vertex[i].distance );
}
```

Comment: I can see how that is simpler, however the maximum amount of vertices is given as UINT_MAX and I have to have it be dynamic, since it is read in from an input file

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson Yes, I've given you a working starting point. You can evolve it to your desired solution one step at time. For example, replace the queue code with a linked-list based queue, and make sure it still works. Then add the edge lists to the vertices to speed up searching the edges, etc. When you've got everything working with static data, then add the code to read data from a file.

Comment: I see, but there is no easy way to port your distance algorithm to my current configuration for vertices and edges is there?